# Is there any way to integrate Dropbox in the messaging menu like ubuntu one?

Tags: dropbox, messaging-menu

Well, what the title says : is there any way to integrate Dropbox in the messaging menu like ubuntu one ?

Edit: Below is an image showing where Ubuntu One is on the messaging menu
That is where I ask if I can put dropbox, NOT on the panel itself.

[image: message menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible (as far as I know) to move DP from its standard place in the traybar to the message menu.
You can only add a shortcut in Message Indicator menu:

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/dropbox`

In the editor, type following text and save:

`/usr/bin/dropbox`

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work - have you done it yourself on your system?

Comment: I did not add DP in my Message menu, but I did the same for other applications. Can you provide additional information on what did not work while trying my solution?

Comment: Eh..nothing happened at all after a restart - dropbox was just on its normal place and nothing was in the messaging menu

Comment: I have clarified my answer.

Comment: Even though the second part of the answer didn't work for me, i tick this one as an answer for the first sentence - which pretty much answers what i asked for. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox 1.0 has support for the App Indicators

http://blog.dropbox.com/?p=581

Comment: The indicator is ok - what i asked for is messaging menu integration like ubuntu one's. 
(==if it is possible to appear in the same place ubuntu one, empathy, evolution etc are)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd previously installed Dropbox, it's likely that the Dropbox daemon hasn't updated, which is part of why you don't see the indicator. To force the update, do this in a terminal window within GNOME:

```
dropbox stop
rm -r ~/.dropbox.dist
dropbox start -i
```

You should then get a pop-up window prompting you about updating Dropbox.

Comment: The indicator is ok - what i asked for is messaging menu integration like ubuntu one's. 
(==if it is possible to appear in the same place ubuntu one, empathy, evolution etc are)

Comment: I thought that messaging thing was an indicator...

Comment: the messaging menu is an indicator, true. but i don't think that you can put any indicator you want inside it, can you? 

Have you seen how ubuntu one works?